# How to replace a String in a String in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I can not replace the string.

The String comes from a textarea

Here the JSFiddle

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpd7szgy/)

```
value.replace('[Bold]', '<strong>');
```

Comment: `value  = value.replace('[Bold]', '<strong>');`

Comment: If you want to replace multiple then use regex with global flag  `value  = value.replace(/\[Bold\]/g, '<strong>');`

Comment: Read docs for replace().... it returns a new string, it does not mutate original and only works on first instance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problems with you code are

- To handle some test text use `g` flag is RexExp
- You `[]` and `/` should be escaped using `\` in RegExp
- Strings are immutable. You need to assign them new value. `value.replace(...)` will not change orginal string

```js
    $('.description:not(.focus)').keyup(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var contentAttr = $(this).attr('name');
        
        value = value.replace(/\[Bold\]/g, '<strong>');
        value = value.replace(/\[\/Bold\]/g, '</strong>');

        value = value.replace(/\[Italic\]/g, '<em>');
        value = value.replace(/\[\/Italic\]/g, '</em>');

        value = value.replace(/\[Underline\]/g, '<u>'); 
        value = value.replace(/\[\/Underline\]/g, '</u>');
        $('.'+contentAttr+'').html(value.replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br/>'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
start typeing in textarea whatever text you type it will also apear in div which has class <strong>'content'</strong> but when I press enter for new line in textarea when i get the problem  div named   <strong>'content'</strong>  will not making new line please help

<br/>
<textarea name="description" rows="15" class="description"></textarea>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="description" >Texts Comes here</div>
```